# How to type a pipe "|" on an HTC EVO Android 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, keyboard

I am using Connect Bot on my HTC EVO Android Version 2.2, and on the keyboard I do not see a "|".  How do I type a pipe, "|" character?  I am trying to run a `ps -ef | grep XYZ` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using stock keyboard, then go to the symbols (?123, bottom left), then press Alt (ALT, vertically second from bottom left), the pipe character is third from top-left.

If on HTC IME, then go to symbols (12#, horizontally second from bottom right), go to the second page (1/2, horizontally second from bottom left), the pipe character is the fifth character in the third row, and the broken pipe character is the sixth character in the second row.

Comment: You are correct my friend, except on the HTC EVO you hit the 1/2 key instead of ALT and I see the pipe.

Comment: On the Droid slide-out keyboard, it's `shift-alt-,`

Comment: On my HTC Wildfire the broken pipe character is as you described, but on the bottom row of my second symbol page I just have emotion buttons! How can I replace these with the remaining symbols?