# How to create a "pipe character" with the HTC Incredible (ConnectBot)?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, keyboard

I am trying to use the | (pipe) character in ConnectBot on my HTC Incredible, but everyone says to use Shift + Alt + ',' but that doesn't seem to work.  I have tried multiple different combinations to no avail.  Any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What keyboard are you using?

Comment: I am using the standard keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No worky. HTC is not calling the correct ASCII code for the "pipe" symbol. It seems there are two of them in existence. One is a straight vertical bar (|) (supposed to be ASCII #124 in base-10 and 7C in hex) and one has a small gap in the center, it is also called the broken line or the broken bar and was used in the old IBM EBCDIC character set.
The confusion is that I have seen UNIX keyboards with the broken line representing the pipe symbol. However, the broken bar is not part of the ASCII set and I have no clue what HTC used for its ASCII representation.
On second thought they must be using an ISO/IEC 8859-1 representation: the vertical bar is 7C (hex) and the broken bar is A6 (hex). There you have it. 
All I can say is that my invisible wireless network has | in it and as long as I hide it, I can't link to it with my Incredible. Making it visible and joining and then making it invisible again does not work as a trick. 
Annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it's the same as on the EVO: [How to type a pipe "|" on an HTC EVO Android 2.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/how-to-type-a-pipe-on-an-htc-evo-android-2-2)

Edit: Looks like they may have used the wrong ASCII / UTF-8 code for the pipe, so it looks the same/similar but isn't actually the right character.  (Reference: [Verizon forums](http://community.vzw.com/t5/DROID-Incredible-by-HTC/Where-is-the-pipe-symbol-on-keyboard/td-p/193576))

I suggest replacing the keyboard then.  [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=871027) has a 2.3 keyboard that should work, it requires root and ROM Manager to flash it.

Comment: The Incredible doesn't have the same layout looks like :(  As for the IME, only the broken pipe is available on the second row, the third row is smiley, sad, etc faces.

Comment: Darn, I assume the broken pipe doesn't work for you?  Updated my answer.

Comment: The broken pipe does indeed not work. `ls | cat` produces something along the lines of `ls: |: No such file or directory
ls: cat: No such file or directory`. A hexdump of my .bash_history reveals that it is sending a two-byte sequence, 0xc2a6. I wonder if maybe my terminfo file could be updated to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try activating the numeric keys (I believe this is done by tapping on the "12#" key to the right of the Spacebar), then hit the shift (or ↑) and that should bring up some alt. symbol keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chrome to phone and copy the character from the a web page and send it to the clipboard on the phone. Then you just paste.

Comment: Yep, good idea. As Brian suggested, you can try to copy the pipe symbol from any other application (like browser) and then paste it to ConnectBot. I tried it and it works. Still better than nothing when you really need it...

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar has a nice, big pipe symbol right near the top, easy for copy & paste. Bookmark that page.

Answer (score 0):

Another good choice: You could e.g. install (and use) [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard), which has special ConnectBot support even for function keys etc.:

> This keyboard is especially useful if you use ConnectBot for SSH access. It provides working Tab/Ctrl/Esc keys, and the arrow keys are essential for devices such as the Xoom tablet or Nexus S that don't have a trackball or D-Pad.

See e.g. the following screenshot, and have a closer look at the "\" key:

[image: Hacker's keyboard normal]

Another screenshot is quite self-explaining:

[image: Hacker's keyboard function keys]

So no need to freak around with copy/pasting from web pages, entering cryptic codes, or the like. Simply use the right keyboard, relax, and enjoy :)